# Team Foundation Server read only permissions

Tags: tfs

Is there a way in Team Foundation Server Administration console so make a user read only so that they can pull down an individual snapshot of the code ion a local pc for testing but not alter any code?

Or is there a way to see the explicit permissions of the default groups such as "Project collection test service accounts" to see if one already does this (both limiting the code to not editable and allowing a snapshot the code to be pulled down locally)

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for under "administer security" in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console under the Team Project Collections tab. The description are incredibly vague and a little hard to parse as a result though and my search has led to nothing on MSDN. If anyone has a link to details about what things like "Alter trace settings, or "Create a workspace" or "Trigger events" means, etc. that would be helpful to me and anyone who reads this later.

Answer (score 1):

I think the administration console is actually not what you want, that's more for administering the TFS installation itself.

If you want to grant a user or group access to the codebase I think the easiest way to do it is through the security settings for the individual project.

If you open up a project through Team Web Access you can click on the cog in the top-right and go to the Version Control tab.

[Picture of version control administration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Yt6.jpg)

In my case There was already a "Readers" group which you could add your users to. If you want to do this you can return to the "Security" tab, choose the "Readers" group, go to Members on the right, and add either a Windows group, or another TFS group.